# Programming style: write new functions or extend existing ones

Tags: coding-style, refactoring

lets say, that I have a form with Image field and function ```getImageWidth()```, that checks Image width. After some time, I am adding a new Mobile Image field to my form and I am wondering, what is the best practice for writing a function to check Mobile Image width - extend the old one function ```getImageWidth()``` (by adding parameter isMobileImage) or writing a new ```getMobileImageWidth()``` function? The code for this new function is almost similar to the old one.

What are your opinions?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that `getMobileImageWidth()` will be better option. For example there is topic [Remove Flag Argument](https://refactoring.com/catalog/removeFlagArgument.html) in Martin Fowler's blog. And in his book [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134757599) he wrote the next statement:

> I dislike flag arguments because they complicate the process of understanding what
> function calls are available and how to call them. My first route into an API is usually
> the list of available functions, and flag arguments hide the differences in the function
> calls that are available. Once I select a function, I have to figure out what values are
> available for the flag arguments. Boolean flags are even worse since they don’t convey
> their meaning to the reader—in a function call, I can’t figure out what true means. It’s
> clearer to provide an explicit function for the task I want to do.

I think it is exactly what you need.